# Ubuntu - Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, virtual-machine

I am trying to upload an entire folder and it's contents to my nectar instance, but am getting the following error:

```
Permission denied (publickey)
lost connection
```

I have successfully uploaded singular files using the mac terminal with:

```
scp -i ~/.ssh/keypair.pem ~/desktop/currentdest/file 
ubuntu@my.ip.add.ress:location
```

but attempting the following (which I believed would upload the whole folder:

```
scp -r ~/.ssh/keypair.pem 
~/desktop/currentdest/ 
my.ip.add.ress:location
```

Has not worked - any ideas?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it rather belongs to askubuntu.com

Comment: Ah okay thank you! Ill post it there